# Can't install ubuntu or lubuntu on macbook 1.1

Tags: boot, system-installation, usb, lubuntu, macbook

I have a macbook 1.1 (core2duo and 2gb ram) and its not detecting the dvd or a usb. I had ubuntu running a while back but then the hard drive died, so theres a empty drive in it right now. I'm using an external disk drive due to the one in the mac is dead. I've tried different disk burner software and iso to usb software but the mac isnt detecting anything. I had it running on ubuntu 14.04 before it died and i cant get any version of ubuntu to run.

Comment: Which iso did you download? Was it `ubuntu-14.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso`? I  assume you can boot to OS X. If so which version?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with xubuntu and lubuntu on macbook pro 1.1, but finally installing 15.04 from the mini.iso (bootable usbstick created with unetbootin) worked for me. Nevertheless there are some boot issues from time to time.